# How to prevent p tag causing gap (new line)

Tags: html, css, class, fonts

I'm using the below `<p>` but it causes a gap between the tick the text after the `</p>`

```
<p class="tick">✓</p> Post messages to friends all over the world.
```

**CSS:**

```
.tick {
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal 
}
```

This is what it looks like:

✓

Post messages to friends all over the world.

but I want it all on the same line instead.

Any ideas?

Comment: You have to reset default `<p>` margin: `.tick { margin: 0; }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of vegijtha works, but you shouldn't use the p-tag here. They have the semantic meaning of a paragraph of text  - use a span-tag instead.

```
<span class="tick">✓</span> Post messages to friends all over the world.
```

Answer (score 2):

display: inline; will do the trick.

```
.tick { 
  display: inline;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: green;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: normal;
}
```

But i think that better approach would be do this in unordered list with custom li bullets.

Answer (score 0):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h4n2sstq/

The first example is obiously your original entry - not good.
In the second example i put the text inside the p tags so they align correctly.

```
<p class="tick">✓ Post messages to friends all over the world.</p>
```

If you don't want to put the text inside the p tags just add a css rule for the tick span with an inline-block or just inline display property.

```
display: inline-block;
```

Good luck!